# Remove a not found Shelveset from Team Explorer Code Review

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

A coworker added me as a Reviewer to one of their Shelvesets. A few days later, they removed that shelf, but it is still listed on my Team Explorer under My Work --> Code Reviews.

When I open this code review I am given the error: `Shelveset X - Shelveset Title; CoworkerName could not be found or you do not have permission to access it.`

Under this it shows I have accepted the CR, but there is nothing else I can do beyond that. I'd like to remove this from My Work items.

Refreshing does not help the issue.